# When should I use underscores between words in Python function names (according to the style guide)?

Tags: python, coding-style

The [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) says that underscores should be used, but many Python built-in functions do not. What should the criteria be for underscores? I would like to stay consistent with Python style guidelines but this area seems a little vague. Is there a good rule of thumb, is it based on my own judgment, or does it just not really matter either way?

For example, should I name my function `isfoo()` to match older functions, or should I name it `is_foo()` to match the style guideline?

Comment: Which ones don't use underscores?

Comment: many of those functions were created before the style guide. The rule of thumb is to use undescores

Comment: @Blender: [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) for instance.

Comment: @Blender `re.findall` `str.startswith`... many others

Comment: @Blender `dict.fromkeys` would be an example off the top of my head. Im guessing its okay for *small* (two-word) function names so they are quick and easy to type

Comment: So if I were implementing a function called something like "isfoo" should I call it `is_foo` despite the conventions of similar functions?

Comment: [Breaking the rules #2](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds): "To be consistent with surrounding code that also breaks it (maybe for historic reasons)"... That's probably the reasoning for the mentioned functions. You should follow the convention

Comment: I'm always happy for any excuse to quote this Prolog article (hat-tip [larsmans](http://stackoverflow.com/users/166749/larsmans)): "Recall that intercaps [camelCase] became popular in programming languages that did not allow underscores within names, such as Pascal and Smalltalk. In using intercaps, one seems to be reverting to the early Middle Ages, when handwritten words were not separated, and thus flouting an important readability tool that is a thousand years old."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The style guide leaves this up to you:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores **as necessary to improve readability.**

In other words, if you feel like adding an underscore to your method name would make it easier to read -- by all means go ahead an throw one (or two!) in there.  If you think that there are enough other similar cases in the standard library, then feel free to leave it out.  **There is no hard rule here** (although others may disagree about that point).  The only thing which I think *is* universally accepted is that you shouldn't use "CapWords" or "camelCase" for your methods.  "CapWords" should be reserved for classes, and I'm not sure of any precedence for "camelCase" anywhere (though I could be wrong about that) ...

Comment: I edited my original question to ask about a doubt I expressed in one of the comments. Do you have anything to add about what is better for that or if the choice matters at all?

Comment: @ssb -- I think that what matters is you pick something for your package/module and stick with it.  For `iswhatever` type functions, I would leave off the underscore because that's what the builtin functions do, but it's really up to you.  Just don't have `isfoo` and `is_bar` in the same project.  That's not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

> The style guide says that underscores should be used, but many Python built-in functions do not.

Using the built-in [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) as an example, [this was written in 1997](http://hg.python.org/cpython/annotate/341fcb7bad90/Python/bltinmodule.c#1621).

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) [wasn't published until 2001](http://hg.python.org/peps/rev/4c31c25bdc03), which may account for this discrepancy.

> What should the criteria be for underscores? I would like to stay consistent with Python style guidelines but this area seems a little vague. Is there a good rule of thumb, is it based on my own judgment, or does it just not really matter either way?

**["When in doubt, use your best judgment."](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)**

It's a style *guide*, not a law! Follow the guide where it is appropriate, bearing in mind the caveats (emphasis my own):

> Function names should be lowercase, with words **separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability**.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only **in contexts where that's already the prevailing style** (e.g. threading.py), **to retain backwards compatibility**.

Therefore...

> For example, should I name my function `isfoo()` to match older functions, or should I name it `is_foo()` to match the style guideline?

You should *probably* call it `isfoo()`, to follow the convention of similar functions. It is readable. ["Readability counts."](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)